# Have hyperref direct citations to a webpage

Tags: hyperref, citing

I am writing a proposal, but will likely need to have the references on a separate website.  Is it possible to get hyperref to redirect all citation links to a website instead of a references section at the end of the document (which is working great).

Thanks!

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
  @article{eady49,
  Author = {Eady, Eric T},
  Journal = {Tellus},
  Pages = {33--52},
  Title = {Long waves and cyclone waves},
  Volume = {1},
  Year = {1949}}   
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\citet{eady49} makes a nice hyperlink to the next page...  
I'd like it to go to \url{http://myweb.ca/References.html}

\clearpage
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{test.bib}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Weclome to [tex.se]!  Can you provide a mock-up of what you wish to achieve.

Comment: Sure: Right now \cite{boo78} renders as Boo, 1978 and hyperref makes that a clickable link to that article in my References page.  I'm wondering if the link can be changed to link to http://myweb.ca/ProposalReferences.html instead. Bonus if it can be linked to  http://myweb.ca/ProposalReferences.html#Boo78

Comment: Do you use a citation management package, such as `natbib`?

Comment: Yes; natbib + bibtex; see example above